# How can i discover the network adapter that exist on my machine?

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

In my application i need to check if some network adapter ( that plug in using USB ) is connected. 
When this plug in is connected i see the new hardware  as network adapter and i need to start to using it -

How can i know in run time is the new hardware is connected ?

P.S: I need to do it using .net framework 2.0

Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate all the network interfaces on your local machine with

System.Net.NetworkInformation.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()

This may give you enough information to determine if the network adapter has been attached.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should take a look at WMI events. If system broadcast information about hardware being connected, it will do it through WMI